Is it possible to always make a URL clickable in an SMS text message?
If I send someone a URL via SMS text message, then it seems like whether or not it's received as a clickable hyperlink depends on the receiving client/app. If it is not hyperlinked then it seems like the user is forced to copy and paste the URL into a browser - which can be challenging.
Is there any way around this issue so that nobody ever has to copy and paste a URL?

It depends on the specific app that you use.
For example, if the app support markdown format, you can send this text which is a clickable URL. text, like Google, this is available in telegram or discord.
if your text message app support other kind of link format, it is also the same theory.
hope helpful.
